# MVC Extension Method Being Loaded Twice

Tags: vb.net, model-view-controller, extension-methods

Here is my extension method:

`Public Module HtmlExtensions
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension 
    Public Function ReverseMapPath(ByVal html As HtmlHelper, ByVal path As String) As String
    Dim appPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~")
    Dim res As String = String.Format("{0}", path.Replace(appPath, "/").Replace("\", "/"))
    Return res
    End Function
    End Module`
My web.config has an entry for my namespace

Everything was working just fine.  I started adding more code to the project and now I get an error that looks like I am loading the extension method twice but I cannot figure out why.  The error is:
`path.page.vbhtml(9): error BC30521: Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'FunctionName' is most specific for these arguments:
    Extension method 'Public Function FunctionName(path As String) As String' defined in 'namespace.Extensions.HtmlExtensions': Not most specific.
    Extension method 'Public Function FunctionName((path As String) As String' defined in 'namespace.Extensions.HtmlExtensions': Not most specific.`

I don't understand why this has just crept up.  Clearly I changed something but undoing everything doesn't help.  The error seems more behind the .net framework.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just ran into this issue. If you read the link CrazyTim commented, the problem comes from VS adding a reference in the project to itself.

If you're running into this issue, VS might have added a reference in your project to itself. Delete the reference, and you'll be right as rain.

Comment: Worked for me. Unload the project, do not change anything and reload the project. That might do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that it was a namespace issue.  My extension class had Global.ProjectName as the namespace.  Once I changed that everything worked.  It must have been loading it twice due to the namespace.

Comment: Thanks, but I still had the problem even after doing this. To resolve, refer to the answer in this thread: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/vsdebug/thread/94f920e6-7015-4879-95d7-a460da309ae1